# How to convert ReplaySubject to string?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an observable called email

```
var email = ReplaySubject<String>.create(bufferSize: 1)
```

how can I get direct value from it?

like `user.email = email.value?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238190/how-to-rxswift-observable-to-value

Answer (score 1):

subjects are acting both as observables and observers so you have to both send and receive from them

```
var email = ReplaySubject<String>.create(bufferSize: 1)
            
email.on(.next("john@somecompany.com"))
            
email.on(.next("smith@somecompany.com"))

let subscriptionOne = email.subscribe(onNext: { string in
    print(string)
})
```